# Showing an activity by clicking in Preferences

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-preferences

I want to show an Activity when user clicks on the following item in my app's settings:

```
<Preference android:title="@string/prefs_about_app" >
    <intent android:action="com.example.myapp.action.SHOW_ABOUT_DIALOG"/>
</Preference>
```

Here is the Activity itself:

```
public class ShowAboutAppActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String SHOW_ABOUT_DIALOG =
            "com.example.myapp.action.SHOW_ABOUT_DIALOG";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String action = getIntent().getAction();

        if(action != null && !action.isEmpty() && action.equalsIgnoreCase(SHOW_ABOUT_DIALOG)) {

            //Building an AlertDialog to show about app dialog

        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I defined the activity in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".settings.ShowAboutAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_about_app" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.myapp.action.SHOW_ABOUT_DIALOG"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But I get this error when I click on the item in the preferences screen:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.myapp.action.SHOW_ABOUT_DIALOG }
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is retrieve the preference in your preference activity or fragment and then override what happens when it is clicked. Preference Fragments and Activities have a method called onPreferenceTreeClick. So just set a key for your preference in the xml and reference that in the code. Something like this...

preference.xml

```
<Preference
   android:key="myKey"
   android:title="CustomIntentPref"
   //...other stuff />


@Override
    public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
            Preference preference) {

     if(preference.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("myKey") {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(PreferenceActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
         startActivity(myIntent);
     } 


}
```

hope that helps!

Comment: thanks this is also possible. I mark it as answer for your try :D

Answer (score 0):

ok the solution is the following:

I removed the check for action from the activity and then I changed the intent filter in the manifest to:

```
<activity
    android:name=".settings.ShowAboutAppActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_show_about_app" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.myapp.action.SHOW_ABOUT_DIALOG"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

then in the preferences xml:

```
<Preference android:title="@string/prefs_about_app" >
    <intent android:action="com.example.myapp.action.SHOW_ABOUT_DIALOG"/>
</Preference>
```

Hope this help others too.